# methods to import outlook mail into thunderbird

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, import

I cannot import mail from Outlook 2012 into Thunderbird using Thunderbird's import wizard. I get this error "Either there is no default mail client or the current mail client cannot fulfill the messaging request". This is Outlook error, and i tried everything i can to fix it. Outlook is set as default mail client, i tried repairing office installation, modifying registry and nothing helped.

Is there another method to import Outlook mail?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This [article](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Import_.pst_files) provides some links and other techniques for importing your Outlook information to Thunderbird.

**Summary:**
You could try to first import to Outlook Express from Outlook and then import from Outlook Express to Thunderbird.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: @MaQleod I considered that but it is a solution to some instances of this problem. It may not be the accepted answer in his specific case but it is a valid answer to the question. Is it my suggestion-style phrasing that you think should be changed?

Comment: Generally speaking, when you pose an answer it should have some documentation showing it is valid and works or a step by step guide that explains to the OP the process. As it stands it appears uncertain and not a compelling method to try. Single line suggestions don't often make for successful answers.